# AOSP - Meaning of CSV in networkAttributes

Tags: xml, android-source

Items of *networkAttributes* contains a comma separated list:

```
<string-array translatable="false" name="networkAttributes">  
  <item>"wifi,1,1,1,-1,true"</item>  
  <item>"ethernet,9,9,9,-1,true"</item>
</string-array>
```

What do the values "wifi,X,Y, ..." mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The constructor takes those values, located here: ***platform/frameworks/base/core/java/android/net/NetworkConfig.java***

Looking like this:

```
 /**
 * input string from config.xml resource.  Uses the form:
 * [Connection name],[ConnectivityManager connection type],
 * [associated radio-type],[priority],[dependencyMet]
 */
public NetworkConfig(String init) {
    String fragments[] = init.split(",");
    name = fragments[0].trim().toLowerCase(Locale.ROOT);
    type = Integer.parseInt(fragments[1]);
    radio = Integer.parseInt(fragments[2]);
    priority = Integer.parseInt(fragments[3]);
    restoreTime = Integer.parseInt(fragments[4]);
    dependencyMet = Boolean.parseBoolean(fragments[5]);
}
```

It is used in a couple of places, for example in:
***platform/frameworks/opt/telephony/src/java/com/android/internal/telephony/dataconnection/DcTracker.java*** in the method `private void initApnContexts()`

Regards!